# Ruby Koans Proxy Project

Tags: ruby, beginner, proxy

I've just finished the Ruby Koans and one of the last projects was creating a Proxy class that sends methods to another class. I was wondering whether you would change anything about my solution (if there's something wrong or a better way to do it). I'm still a beginner and I want to get better.

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/edgecase')

# Project: Create a Proxy Class
#
# In this assignment, create a proxy class (one is started for you
# below).  You should be able to initialize the proxy object with any
# object.  Any messages sent to the proxy object should be forwarded
# to the target object.  As each message is sent, the proxy should
# record the name of the method send.
#
# The proxy class is started for you.  You will need to add a method
# missing handler and any other supporting methods.  The specification
# of the Proxy class is given in the AboutProxyObjectProject koan.

class Proxy
  attr_reader(:messages)

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    if @methods_to_pass.include?(method_name.to_s)
      @messages << method_name
      @object.__send__(method_name, *args, &block)
    else
      super(method_name, *args, &block)
    end
  end

  def called?(method_name)
    @messages.include?(method_name)
  end

  def number_of_times_called(method_name)
    @messages.count(method_name)
  end

  def initialize(target_object)
    @methods_to_pass, @messages = [], []
    @object = target_object
    @object.class.instance_methods(true).each { |method_name| @methods_to_pass << method_name; method_name }
  end

end

# The proxy object should pass the following Koan:
#
class AboutProxyObjectProject < EdgeCase::Koan
  def test_proxy_method_returns_wrapped_object
    # NOTE: The Television class is defined below
    tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)

    assert tv.instance_of?(Proxy)
  end

  def test_tv_methods_still_perform_their_function
    tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)

    tv.channel = 10
    tv.power

    assert_equal 10, tv.channel
    assert tv.on?
  end

  def test_proxy_records_messages_sent_to_tv
    tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)

    tv.power
    tv.channel = 10

    assert_equal [:power, :channel=], tv.messages
  end

  def test_proxy_handles_invalid_messages
    tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)

    assert_raise(NoMethodError) do
      tv.no_such_method
    end
  end

  def test_proxy_reports_methods_have_been_called
    tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)

    tv.power
    tv.power

    assert tv.called?(:power)
    assert ! tv.called?(:channel)
  end

  def test_proxy_counts_method_calls
    tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)

    tv.power
    tv.channel = 48
    tv.power

    assert_equal 2, tv.number_of_times_called(:power)
    assert_equal 1, tv.number_of_times_called(:channel=)
    assert_equal 0, tv.number_of_times_called(:on?)
  end

  def test_proxy_can_record_more_than_just_tv_objects
    proxy = Proxy.new("Code Mash 2009")

    proxy.upcase!
    result = proxy.split

    assert_equal ["CODE", "MASH", "2009"], result
    assert_equal [:upcase!, :split], proxy.messages
  end
end


# ====================================================================
# The following code is to support the testing of the Proxy class.  No
# changes should be necessary to anything below this comment.

# Example class using in the proxy testing above.
class Television
  attr_accessor :channel

  def power
    if @power == :on
      @power = :off
    else
      @power = :on
    end
  end

  def on?
    @power == :on
  end
end

# Tests for the Television class.  All of theses tests should pass.
class TelevisionTest < EdgeCase::Koan
  def test_it_turns_on
    tv = Television.new

    tv.power
    assert tv.on?
  end

  def test_it_also_turns_off
    tv = Television.new

    tv.power
    tv.power

    assert ! tv.on?
  end

  def test_edge_case_on_off
    tv = Television.new

    tv.power
    tv.power
    tv.power

    assert tv.on?

    tv.power

    assert ! tv.on?
  end

  def test_can_set_the_channel
    tv = Television.new

    tv.channel = 11
    assert_equal 11, tv.channel
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm also experimenting with Ruby, and am looking for examples/a tutorial/exercises which discuss the more advanced ruby features. I finished the chapter in 7 languages in 7 weeks, but apparently [there is more to ruby](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/147/topics/4414). Judging from the index of files of the koans it is also quite limited. Any other resources, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 11):

```
@methods_to_pass, @messages = [], []
@object = target_object
@object.class.instance_methods(true).each { |method_name| @methods_to_pass << method_name; method_name }
```

Couple of things to note here:

First of all the `; method_name` bit is completely unnecessary. I don't know why you put that there, but it serves no purpose and just confuses the reader.

Secondly `foo = []; bar.each {|x| foo << x}` is an overly verbose way to copy an array. You can just say `foo = bar.dup`. However in this case there is no reason to perform a copy, so you can just say `foo = bar`, i.e. `@methods_to_pass = @object.class.instance_methods(true)` (but don't - see below).

That being said storing the methods in an array like that is a bad idea for two reasons:

1. Since checking whether an item is in an array is `O(n)`, your `method_missing` method and thus every proxied call becomes `O(n)`. This is needlessly inefficient.
2. If `@object` has singleton methods or dynamically defined methods, those won't be forwarded as they won't show up in `@object.class.instance_methods`.

To fix these issues you should get rid of `@methods_to_pass` and instead use one of the following approaches:

Option a:

In `method_missing` replace `if @methods_to_pass.include?(method_name.to_s)` with `if @object.respond_to?(method_name)`. This will be faster than searching through an array and it will also work for dynamically defined or singleton methods. However it will not work if `@object` has a custom `method_missing` method and does not override `respond_to?` to be in sync with `method_missing`. If you want to handle that case as well, you'll need to use one of the other two options.

Option b:

Just remove the whole `if` and always forward (and record) the method call. This way the behavior will be different from your code as invalid calls will be recorded in `@messages`. However since they will still cause a `NoMethodError` and the assignment doesn't actually state whether invalid calls should be recorded or not, it still meets the requirements.

---

Now let's talk about the `@messages` array:

Using an array to store the messages and then using `count` to find out how often a given message appears is again needless inefficient. What I'd do instead is use a `Hash` which maps each message to the number of times it's been called. This way you'd write `@message = Hash.new(0)` instead of `@messages = []`, `@messages[method_name] += 1` instead of `@messages << method_name` and `@messages[method_name]` instead of `@messages.count(method_name)`.

Answer (score 3):

sepp2k's responses are all good, I would add one more suggestion.  Your Proxy class should derive from BasicObject (if you use ruby 1.9.x).  At the moment any method defined on `Proxy` is by definition *not* missing.  For example given:

```
foo = Foo.new
pfoo = Proxy.new(foo)
```

if I asked for `pfoo.class` I would get `Proxy` because `class` is a method in the inheritance of Proxy.  With `BasicObject` this would instead return `Foo` and add an entry for `"class"` in the proxy object.

One other nit to pick, I would add an underscore in front of `called` and `number_of_times_called`.  Putting an underscore in a method is a clue to other programmers that the method is outside the normal operation of a class.  In this case it will help prevent name collision with the object you are going to proxy to.  The truly paranoid would actually call a method on a separate object to count calls leaving the entire namespace unused.  Think what would happen if you tried to proxy a `Proxy` instance. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my view, there were problems with every one of the suggested solutions, which is why I took a different approach: the wrapper class dynamically programs itself during object initialization: it just "implements" *every single public method* (except for a few system-specific ones) of the wrapped class by recording its name and forwarding the call to the wrapped object.

In this way, not only methods that are ***not*** defined in the wrapper class are forwarded, but also (most of) those that ***are*** defined. This is crucial if the wrapped class (`Television` in this example) overwrites some standard method such as `to_s`. In all the other solutions above, sending the `to_s` message to the wrapper object will just call the wrapper's `to_s` (inherited from `Object`). In my solution, the method being called really is the wrapped object's **own** `to_s` method.

Moreover, I think my approach is the only one here that makes the wrapper object reply to `respond_to?` correctly, i.e. returning `true` for all the methods defined in the wrapped class.

```
class Proxy
  attr_reader :messages   # return an array of messages called

  def initialize(target_object)
    @object = target_object
    @methods_called = Hash.new(0);
    @messages = [] # Array for storing the message names

    # For each of the object's methods
    methods_to_forward = @object.methods - [:__send__, :object_id, :instance_of?, :method_missing]
    methods_to_forward.each do |method|
        eval """ def #{method}(*args, &block)
                    @methods_called[:#{method}] += 1
                    @messages.push :#{method}
                    @object.send(:#{method}, *args, &block)
                 end            
             """
    end
  end

  def called? method
    number_of_times_called(method) > 0 
  end

  def number_of_times_called(method)
    @methods_called[method]
  end
end
```